# MS Word replace weird character

Tags: ms-word

I have a word file that is a converted file from a pdf. In that pdf, there were linebreaks used with hyphens. In the word file, that is also done, however I want those gone. However, the character is not just a hyphen, but some weird character that I cannot replace:   [image: Screenshot of weird character]

When i copy paste it, I get this '­'. As you can see, nothing is there. How can i replace this character. It may also be achieved by VBA.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to capture one and then use find and replace with nothing. Here the word is evidencebased ! and thus dubious as to the value of replacing with nothing when in reality a hyphen for this one of 99 would be more appropriate.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Another option in simpler cases is ensure the text is converted to plain text (not Unicode) then  you should see the non ascii characters as ? which you can replace with conventional hyphens where required.

[image]